# Boolean.parseboolean not working to evaluate a computed boolean expression

Tags: java, string, boolean

I'm trying to solve a java program where we have to evaluate a string expression and return true or false. The expression may be like this **s=(F&F|V|!V&!F&!(F|F&V))** where V is for true, F is for false. I thought that replacing V for true and F for false would work. But the output is not as desired Please tell me if I'm wrong.

My code is like this

```
 String temp="";
 for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
 {
    char ch=s.charAt(i);
    if(ch=='V')
    {
        temp+="true";
        continue;
    }
    else if(ch=='F')
    {
        temp+="false";
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        temp+=ch;
        continue;
    }           
 }
 boolean t=Boolean.parseBoolean(temp); 
 out.println(temp);
 out.println(t);
 return t;
```

Comment: *Highly recommended:* **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Boolean.parseBoolean(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-), to learn what the method *actually* does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static boolean evalBooleanExpression(String s) {
    return new Object() {
        int index = 0;
        int ch = get();
        
        int get() { return ch = index < s.length() ? s.charAt(index++) : -1; }
        
        boolean eat(int ex) {
            while (Character.isWhitespace(ch))
                get();
            if (ch != ex) return false;
            get();
            return true;
        }
        
        boolean paren() {
            boolean r = expression();
            if (!eat(')')) throw new RuntimeException("')' expected");
            return r;
        }

        boolean factor() {
            boolean not = false;
            if (eat('!')) not = true;
            if (eat('V')) return !not;
            else if (eat('F')) return not;
            else if (eat('(')) return not ^ paren();
            else throw new RuntimeException("unknown char '" + ((char)ch) + "'");
        }

        boolean term() {
            boolean r = factor();
            while (eat('&'))
                r &= factor();
            return r;
        }

        boolean expression() {
            boolean r = term();
            while (eat('|'))
                r |= term();
            return r;
        }
        
        boolean parse() {
            boolean r = expression();
            if (ch != -1)
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "extra string '" + s.substring(index - 1) + "'");
            return r;
        }

    }.parse();
}
```

and

```
String s = "(F&F | V |!V&!F&!(F| F&V))";
System.out.println(evalBooleanExpression(s));
```

output:

```
true
```

Comment: yeah this helped..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean.parseBoolean(s)` is equivalent to `"true".equalsIgnoreCase(s)`; it does not evaluate a logical expression. Instead, you could use the JavaScript engine.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
//...
try {
    String s = "(F&F|V|!V&!F&!(F|F&V))";
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(engine.eval(s.replace("F", "false")
       .replace("V", "true").replace("&", "&&").replace("|", "||")).toString());
    System.out.println(b);
} catch(ScriptException e){
    // Handle
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is some sort of homework assignment, I'd expect an acceptable solution would require actually parsing the expression to evaluate it, not just feeding it into some other compiler.

Comment: yeah but can you please tell an alternative in java....i'm new to js and don't know how to use engine. is there a problem with parse conversion or compiler evaluating the boolean expression?

Comment: @samcodes007 My answer shows how to use the JavaScript engine in Java. It also explains why `Boolean.parseBoolean` does not work.

Comment: @samcodes007 You can see a demo of this working here: https://ideone.com/RxD0KD

Comment: Well, you could equivalently write a Java program that emitted a Java program `boolean F=false, V=true, s=(F&F|V|!V&!F&!(F|F&V)) ; println(s);` -- wrapped in the usual boilerplate, of course -- and fed that to the Java compiler.  But that seems like avoiding the question.

Comment: @iota I'm getting this error....probably because my compiler is not able to evaluate js engine Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "<local2>" is null

Comment: @user15187356 i tried the way u said...expression is evaluating to be false instead of true.. any idea?

Comment: Not possible unless you made a mistake.